# Idea Apex Live Templates

Tags: apex, format

has anyone used any Idea Live Template for Salesforce? I have recently moved from Sublime to IntelliJ and I was wondering whether any of you has some promising experience with using a specific template. I have found a few (e.g. https://github.com/SergeyTrusov/idea-apex-live-template), but I would like to get a sense of what people generally use. I should also add that I have returned to Salesforce development after 4/5 years, so apologies If I am asking trivial questions!

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say you're using IntelliJ, do you mean you're using it with Illuminated Cloud?

Illuminated Cloud comes with a collection of live templates:

http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/home/completion/livetemplates

I've added a couple of my own for testing Visualforce e.g.

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.$PAGE$;
Map<String, String> params = pageRef.getParameters();

Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

$TYPE$ controllerExtension = new 
    $TYPE$(new ApexPages.StandardController(new $SOBJECT$()));
```

If you've been away a while, it's worth noting Salesforce themselves are pushing Visual Studio Code with their own plugin. I still prefer Illuminated Cloud, but you may want to keep an eye on VS Code.

Comment: Thank you @Aidan, much appreciated. I need to refresh any previous knowledge of SF as well as new trends, approaches, etc